# steps to automate a flex application using flex monkey and selenium

Tags: java, apache-flex, selenium, flex-monkey

Am trying to automate a sample Flex application using Flex Monkium and selenium.
The steps and sample application (MonkeyContacts) are given in gorilla logic site http://www.gorillalogic.com/testing-tools/flexmonkium/flexmonkium-docs/using-flexmonkium . 
After following the steps in the above application i am able to record the tests using Selenium IDE and able to run those tests using Eclipse and TestNG.

But when am trying to do the same steps in other applications ( http://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/Flex/Download+Projects ) , not able to record the tests. There is no interaction between Flex Monkey and Selenium. I have added the automation-monkey.swc and added the Additional compiler arguments also.

How to make the application to interact with selenium..?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Gorilla logic has beautify stated all related steps for flex monkey automation, I'll say you give it a look again. [Flex monkey documentation](http://www.gorillalogic.com/node/333)

Apart from this always make sure

1. Flex monkium console icon turns green (if not its **NOT** compiled properly, check compiler arguments.
2. Use firefox version 10 or less. Selenium is not compatible with later versions.

Comment: flex monkey is the best tool out there, I've done alot of research. you should not face much problems.